# Why does this wslite SOAP client code not work?

Tags: grails, soap, groovy

Im new to Groovy and Im working on a Grails app. I need to make a SOAP call so Im using the `wslite` package, but the following code doesn't appear to do anything:

> ```
>         def client = new SOAPClient(apiEndpoint)
>         println "SOAP client is ${client.dump()}"
>         try {
>             def response = client.send(SOAPAction: 'GetService') {
>                 body {
>                         "Request" {
>                             "Username"(credentials.userId)
>                             "Password"(credentials.password)
>                             "Param1"(code)
>                             "Param2"(location)
>                             "Items" {
>                                 "Item" {
>                                     "ItemParam1"("some data")
>                                     "ItemParam2"(some more data)
>                                 }
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         } catch (SOAPFaultException sfe) {
>             println "${sfe.dump()}"
>         } catch (SOAPClientException sce) {
>             println "${sce.dump()}"
>         }
>         println "${response.dump()}"
> ```

The first `println` works but then nothing after that.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a catch all for exceptions I was able to see the problem in the markup.